# How to consume SOAP/REST web services on Android (Service/Broadcast/Intent/etc)

Tags: android, rest, soap, webservice-client, android-service

Is there a common way to consume web services from Android applications (aside from the protocol)? What I need is a `Service` or `Intent` or `Thread` (or anything else) that is capable of:

1. staying alive no matter what Activities are open;
2. be able to perform multiple requests at the same time;
3. accept input values and return output values to the right caller;
4. be able to discard an ongoing operation (while keeping to run all the others) and not to return the output value if it is no longer desired;
5. (of course) run asynchronously.

Is there a common way to accomplish this? I've had some issues while using Services, primarily because I wasn't able to discard an ongoing operation, so the results were colliding with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmm you need a combination of things here. First of all, you need a service layer implement it with a [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) (inherits). Your UI activities must call this service through an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).
Then, this layer that would be execute it in a different thread than your UI layer, must have a Rest Client object to perform services calls.
Here you have lot of approaches, I recommend you [Spring Rest](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) implementation as well as [Restlet](http://wiki.restlet.org/developers/172-restlet/g1/271-restlet.html).

As is a pretty big discussion, anything else please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Service` for this task. This is the only component that was designed to handle background long-running tasks. Most likely you need to use this service as a "locally bound" to pass complex requests and responses without need for serialization, and to perform other tasks that are relatively hard to implement via `Intent`s.

Read more about locally bound services here: [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html).

Comment: I would recommend an AsyncTask over a service for this if the operation is going to be performed in the app.  You get the benefit of a clearer structure (onPreExecute, doInBackGround, onPostExecute) and it's a bit simpler to implement.  It sounds like this isn't quite what MacGyver wants, but I thought it was useful information. (hence the comment instead of the answer)

Comment: The `Binder` in the `Service` is going to have multiple methods, one for each request to the web service. How should I differentiate each callback? Should I pass the `Binder`'s method a Listener? And if I don't need the callback, how do I destroy the listener before the Activity's destroy?

Comment: Why don't you run an AsyncTask in the service?  That was you can use a callback from the AsyncTask into your service to call an event handler to do what you want when the service responds.

Comment: Personally I do not like to put web-service calls into activity. It complicates it, and now you need to take care about activity lifecycle (like configuration change) in a very careful manner. There are quite some pitfalls there.

Comment: @inazaruk, what are you suggesting to do?

Comment: Stick with locally bound service, its a bit more work at first. But saves a lot of time/headache in long term.